# Difficulty compiling a file on openshift: /usr/bin/ld/: cannot find -lpython2.7

Tags: python, linux, openshift, openshift-cartridge, nuitka

I recently put a simple web app on Openshift. Everything functions well on my local machine but when I run the application on Openshift I receive the error:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7

The app uses Nuitka and gnu++ to convert a python file to an executable. I'm assuming the location of python is different which is causing the problem. I've located Python in the Openshift app and attempted to create a symlink to /usr/bin/ld after logging into the app but I get the message "permission denied." Here is the error:

ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/lib/python2.7/python2.7': Permission denied

I believe creating a link would solve my issue but Openshift doesn't seem to like that idea. Is there a way to change permissions so that this will work? Or is there an alternative way to make a link or fix the issue?

Comment: Can you provide more details on your app?

Comment: Sure, it is a simple web app made with Python and Flask. It allows a user to point the app to an outside python file which gets uploaded to the server and converted to an executable file using Nuitka. Nuitka does all of the work.The user manual for Nuitka can be found here  http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html. There are several dependencies but they have all been installed on Openshift. I believe the problem is Nuitka is attempting to reference Python but it is located in a location Nuitka not expect on Openshift and I am not able to change the location.